Fixing TFT flexible pcb
I have damaged the flexible/ribon pcb on my display (as shown in the pictures below). I was thinking about soldering it, but the traces are tiny. Replacement isn’t possible.
What do you guys think i should do?
Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Best regards



Ouch! How's your patience and how much do you value your time versus how much a new one cost? The base material has rather low melting point so it makes solder difficult.

'Truly' is a fairly large maker, you might have luck in finding a replacement.

A fix like that could take weeks and still might not yield a working result, especially if those signals are impedance controlled. It looks like you might need 36 AWG wire to do that, that would require super soldering skills.

If replacement isn't possible, the only option left is repair. Such repair requires very careful soldering with tons of precision, but it's not impossible.
From what I can see in the photo, there are more than 30 broken traces on the front side of flexible PCB. Most likely the back side is just a copper polygon (hatched fill similar to visible polygons) connected to ground. If it's the case, you are in luck, only the front side requires tedious repair, and on the back side only the continuity of the ground plane needs to be checked. The worst case is the back side of the PCB has another 30+ broken traces, but I really doubt that's the case.
What you can do to make the repair a bit easier is take a high resolution scan (or photo) of the broken part, trace every connection, then route a small PCB that would repeat the pattern of the original tracks (doesn't have to be exact, only the coordinates of the track beginning and end is what matters, these parts should not be covered by the solder mask). Then you can order this PCB to be manufactured professionally. Finally, you will need to cut out a segment of the PCB of exact dimensions of your replacement part with a sharp blade and scrap off the solder mask from the ends of the broken traces. The replacement should fit in the hole, and the exposed traces should match, solder them together to restore connections.
Alternatively, you can restore every broken trace individually by soldering a tiny wire to a undamaged segment scraped with a needle to expose copper. This is cheaper than getting a PCB made, but can be even more tedious.
Whatever technique you choose (either a patch or a lot of tiny wires), I recommend first searching for a donor device with a similar screen. It's possible that someone has a product with a dead motherboard, but with a working screen. Getting it for replacement parts is probably the easiest and the cheapest solution.

Thanks for an answer. Do you have any idea how to remove that yellow protective layer over traces? It is some kind of polymer.

From my experience, you can't dissolve this protective layer chemically without damaging everything around. The best way is to do it mechanically, I usually use a sharp needle for this.
